# how to creat a javascript function that combine input values from user input and out put them in a phrase?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to creat a resume builder project to learn javascript. how can i creat a function that combine input value of a user, and output them in one phrase, some thing like this

```html
<form>
    <input type:"text" id:"position">
    <input type:"text" id:"startdate">
    <input type:"date" id:"enddate">
</form>
```

and get this result:

> - started working as a **position** from **startdate** to **enddate**

with the ability to add new fieldset dynamicly if the user want to, that will be desplayed in a new phrase the same way just with new input

Comment: `i'm trying to creat a javascript function` Where? What exactly is the roadblock you're running into, can you post your code?

Comment: yes it was just a mistake, i corrected it

Comment: sorry - but you have created a new mistake with your correction of hte old mist :)

Comment: It is all correct now. I'm new here this is my first question ever

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, your question is unclear. What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve?
Here are a simple example is to get you started. Just get the value of each field, and combine the value into a string.

```
function combineText() {
  var position = document.getElementById('position').value;
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

  var text = "started working as a "+position+" from "+startDate+" to "+endDate+".";

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a94nwf17/1/) example with event listener and form.

Comment: thanks bro, that's exactly what i was looking for, i did this before just forgot, i tried to creat a resume maker, i'm still stuck on the second part, how to add new fieldset for when the user try to write new phrase (li) to his expersience

Comment: Glad I could help. However you still not accept my answer, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Thanks